# What's a good way to install "build essentials" (all common useful commands) on a blank EC2 Linux server?

Tags: linux, unix, installation, amazon-ec2

I want to get some "build essentials" (like gcc, make, etc.) on an empty micro Linux box.  Seems inefficient to spend my time trying to try installing one thing, then realize I need gcc, then realize I need make, then realize I need something else.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Depends on your distro, and what you're going to build.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most distributions have "build-essentials" or an equivalent package, either as an option or installed by default.

- In Debian-based distros, this would be the `build-essential` package, which you can install with `apt-get install build-essential`.
- In Fedora/Red Hat-based distros, this would be the "Development Tools" group, which you can install with  `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`.
- In SUSE Linux-based distros, this would be the "Base Development" (`devel_basis`) pattern, which you can install with `zypper install --type pattern devel_basis`.

You could also compile the software you need into packages with `checkinstall` using another system, then move them over, if for some reason you didn't want a full development environment on the instance of EC2 you are using.

Comment: On SLES SP1, i ran `zypper install --type pattern Basis-Devel`